# Find distance between a point and nearest intersection using osmnx

Tags: networkx, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am a student using osmnx to process some data. I have lat and long of a point somewhere on a road (it is sure that the point lies on a road), is there a way by which I can find the path distance between the nearest intersection and that point?

Comment: Have you try  this?https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.euclidean_dist_vec

Comment: The concept of "path distance" (ie, the spatially-weighted distance along the graph's edges) only makes sense with nodes as origins and destinations, as edges merely exist as links between nodes. You can find the Euclidean (or great-circle) distance between an arbitrary point and a node and then calculate graph paths. Or you can create new nodes at arbitrary points if you want.